# syntax error with mysql trigger query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

so I have the following query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete`
    BEFORE DELETE ON `abc` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM def WHERE OLD.id = objID1 OR OLD.id = objID2;
        DELETE FROM ghi WHERE OLD.id = objID;
    END;
```

but then mysql complains that there's syntax error near 'END' at line 1....

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of the `DELIMTIER` trick to include multiple statements in a procedure block. Otherwise it can't tell the difference between the end of your procedure and the end of statements inside it. On the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) page, there is an example using the delimiter keyword.

To save you the trouble of going to that page and looking around, I think this will fix it:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete`
BEFORE DELETE ON `abc` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM def WHERE OLD.id = objID1 OR OLD.id = objID2;
    DELETE FROM ghi WHERE OLD.id = objID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```